# alternative to VideoCapture::set in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been writing a code in which i have to take 2 frames per iteration for absdiff();
`cp>>frame1;
cp>>frame2;
absdiff(frame1,frame2,out)`
frame1 was getting 0,2,4,6,8,10,....
frame2 was getting 1,3,5,7,9,11,....
I am not getting all the combinations of frame1,frame2.
LET'S CALL THIS PROCESS-1

But,I needed frame1 as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,..... and
frame2 as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,......
So,I used

```
 cp.set(CV_CAP_PROPS_POS_FRAMES,cp.get(CV_CAP_PROPS_POS_FRAMES)-1);
```

to set the next frame number to that of frame2 instead of frame2+1.Now ,I am getting my desired output.
I am getting all the combinations of frame1,frame2.
LET'S CALL THIS PROCESS-2
But, processing speed PROCESS-2 is nearly 1/5 to that of the  PROCESS-1
So,I am guessing setting the VideoCapture property i.e next frame position is responsible for decreasing the speed.Am I wrong?If not, Is there any other way to get my desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not wrong. Repositioning the video this way is very slow. You're better reading frames in sequence and handling the pairing yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice